# Pandas - find other values in duplicates

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Say I have the following dataframe

```
Name  Value
foo1  abc
foo2  abc
foo3  efg
foo4  xyz
foo5  abc
```

There are duplicates. 'foo1', 'foo2', and 'foo3' all have the same value.

How do I get a list of the duplicates? What I'm looking for is this

```
Name  Value   Dupes
foo1  abc     foo1, foo2, foo5
foo2  abc     foo1, foo2, foo5
foo3  efg     foo3
foo4  xyz     foo4
foo5  abc     foo1, foo2, foo5
```

or

```
Name  Value   Dupes
foo1  abc     foo2, foo5
foo2  abc     foo1, foo5
foo3  efg     
foo4  xyz     
foo5  abc     foo1, foo2
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `groupby.agg`, then `map`:

```
df['Dupes'] = df['Value'].map(df.groupby('Value')['Name'].agg(', '.join))
```

Output:

```
   Name Value             Dupes
0  foo1   abc  foo1, foo2, foo5
1  foo2   abc  foo1, foo2, foo5
2  foo3   efg              foo3
3  foo4   xyz              foo4
4  foo5   abc  foo1, foo2, foo5
```

Answer (score 1):

We do `transform` with `groupby`

```
df['new'] = df.groupby('Value')['Name'].transform(','.join)
Out[112]: 
0    foo1,foo2,foo5
1    foo1,foo2,foo5
2              foo3
3              foo4
4    foo1,foo2,foo5
Name: Name, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

The second example given differs from the first output example, due to non duplicated values having no names in the `Dupes` column. Here is a way to handle that, as well as ensuring only unique names are displayed in the `Dupes` column.

```
(df.assign(Dupes = df['Value'].map((df.groupby('Value')['Name']
                                    .agg(set)
                                    .where(lambda x: x.str.len().gt(1))
                                    .map(','.join,na_action='ignore')))))
```

Here is an alternative way:

```
(df.assign(Dups = df.loc[df.duplicated(subset=['Value'],keep=False)]
           .groupby('Value')['Name']
           .transform(lambda x: ','.join(set(x)))))
```

Output:

```
   Name Value            Dups
0  foo1   abc  foo1,foo2,foo5
1  foo2   abc  foo1,foo2,foo5
2  foo3   efg             NaN
3  foo4   xyz             NaN
4  foo5   abc  foo1,foo2,foo5
```

Just noticed that the `Dups` column has only the names in the other rows. Try this:

```
(df.assign(Dups = df['Value'].map(df.groupby('Value')['Name'].agg(set))
           .sub(df['Name'].map(lambda x: set(x.split())))
           .map(','.join)))
```

Output:

```
   Name Value       Dups
0  foo1   abc  foo5,foo2
1  foo2   abc  foo5,foo1
2  foo3   efg           
3  foo4   xyz           
4  foo5   abc  foo1,foo2
```